Furnace Exhaust Flue Behind A/C
My furnace exhaust is sitting directly behind my A/C unit. Doesn;t this pose a risk of bringing exhaust fumes into our home and potentially damaging the A/C unit? I love in the U.S. Is this a code violation?


I would consider adding a 90º elbow to add a turndown to that upper pipe.

@Huesmann, no. You don't direct exhaust toward the intake.

Loving in the US remains legal, for the time being, although hating is trending.

@jay613 Hmmm. May depend on the state. Definitely OK in Virginia, not sure about some of the others.

@manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact Virginia is a VERY ironic choice of example to use right now, especially given the Loving word play here.

The outside unit does not interact with your inside air,
Instead it compresses and condenses a refrigerant after which the liquid refrigerant gets pushed to the inside air handler where it is made to evaporate and suck away heat from the air being pushed around your home.
There is no combustion products getting mixed with inside air through that path.

Thank you. Does the exhaust flue pose a risk of damaging the A/C unit down the line?

It shouldn't, if you are worried about that you can extend the upright until it's above the outside unit. Make sure to support it as needed though

There are two concerns:

Combustion Products - CO, CO2, particulates

The outdoor A/C unit is sealed, so none of this can get into the house, and none of this will, under any reasonably anticipated situation (furnace causing a house fire being different, but then your A/C unit is the least of your problems) cause any damage to the fan, motor, compressor, etc.

Hot Exhaust

This used to be a concern, but not any more. You have PVC intake and exhaust vents. That means you have a high-efficiency (90% or better) furnace. That means the exhaust is not very hot - typically 110 F to 140 F. Older, less efficient, furnaces had higher exhaust temperatures and metal vents. In fact, not only can you not use PVC for older furnaces (it would be at risk of deforming or even melting due to the heat), you can't use metal for newer furnaces because of condensate. Water is a normal product of natural gas combustion. With a high-efficiency furnace, the exhaust temperature is low enough that the water condenses in the exhaust and drips back down into the furnace where it is (hopefully) removed. This condensate is not pure water and can be quite corrosive, which makes PVC a much better choice than metal.
In any case, at 140 F max., the exhaust is not hot enough to be of any concern for the A/C unit. In theory it would lower A/C efficiency if the furnace and A/C ran at the same time. But if that happens then you have much bigger problems to worry about.

Yes this is mildly problematic - not an emergency, mind you, but it shouldn't have been done this way. The two problems I see are these:

Exhausting to a semi-restricted space. The exhaust stream, exiting the upper pipe and hitting the side of the AC condenser, may tend to swirl right there in the immediate area rather than be ejected further away from the building. This means a greater amount of exhaust could be drawn into the intake which may in turn cause incomplete combustion, reduced efficiency, and increased probability of producing carbon monoxide (CO). I suppose there's a chance it could get so bad as to actually produce soot which would also be a problem. Fortunately these problems should all be outside the house because the furnace appears to be the sealed combustion type.
Corrosion of the AC condenser coils. Exhaust gas is mildly acidic. It may happen that water vapor together with the acidic compounds in the exhaust stream could condense on the aluminum fins and aluminum or copper tubing in the condenser. This, in turn, could cause corrosion and eventually premature failure.

The fix is easy enough. You'll need two 2" PVC couplers, about a foot of pipe, and some PVC cement. Cut and extend the vertical section so that the outlet of the upper elbow is 6-12 inches (or more) higher than the top of the AC condenser.

Fix it.
There is no risk of exhaust air entering your house from this arrangement.  The A/C condenser does not handle air from the house at all.   It sucks air in through its sides and blows it out the top.
There is however risk that the furnace exhaust could damage your A/C condenser.  You should fix this   The easiest way would be to extend the riser a little so it blows over the top of the condenser instead of straight into the delicate coils.
Exhaust gas from high efficiency furnaces is corrosive.  Blowing it into the coils, where it might condense on the coils which in the winter are nice and cold, and may eventually eat through them causing premature leaks.
